# NullPointerException on GSON Parsing

Tags: android, gson

I use GSON to parse JSON data, and my app is currently able to parse Google Geocoder with this. But, whenever I try to parse JSON from another website it gives nullpointerexception

This is my EventResponse Class which makes the connection btw GSON and [website](http://etrafimdakietkinlikler.herokuapp.com/api/v1/event/?format=json)

```
public class EventResponse {
    public Meta meta;
    public Objects[] Objects;

    public EventResponse() {}

    public class Meta {
        public int limit;
        public String next;
        public int offset;
        public String previous;
        public int total_count;
    }

    public class Objects {
        public String category;
        public String date;
        public String description;
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String resource_uri;
        public String venue;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 7
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "category": "/api/v1/category/1/",
            "date": "2013-05-01",
            "description": "BeÅŸ yakÄ±n arkadaÅŸ, ", //Description is longer in real
            "id": 10,
            "name": "KÃ¶tÃ¼ Ruh / Evil Dead",
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/event/10/",
            "venue": "/api/v1/venue/3/"
        },
        {
            "category": "/api/v1/category/1/",
            "date": "2013-05-02",
            "description": "Filmde, kÃ¼Ã§Ã¼mseyen, ",
            "id": 9,
            "name": "KorkunÃ§ Bir Film 5 / Scary Movie 5",
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/event/9/",
            "venue": "/api/v1/venue/6/"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I use GSON (I tried Objects[0] also, it didn't matter)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
        EventResponse eResult = new EventResponse();
        try {
            eResult = gson.fromJson(jsonCoord((catURL + Categories.catID)),
                    EventResponse.class);

            Log.i("ama"+eResult.Objects[1].category, "deneme");
```

jsonCoord method

```
public String jsonCoord(String address) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String jsonResult = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonResult += inputLine;
        }
        in.close();
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

and I cannot get any value even from the Log. The error stack is like this: (line 59 is the log line)

```
05-02 21:48:32.020: W/System.err(17456): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at com.myapp.myapp.Events.getVenue(Events.java:59)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at com.myapp.myapp.Events.onCreate(Events.java:48)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-02 21:48:32.030: W/System.err(17456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-02 21:48:32.035: W/System.err(17456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-02 21:48:32.035: W/System.err(17456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It may or may not be the cause of your problem, but having an array containing objects of type "Objects" that is also called "Objects" in the same class that defines the type "Objects" is certainly poor practice.

Comment: Oops, it is "objects" in the original JSON. So that was causing the problem. But the weird thing is http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/ made the transition :/

Comment: Glad to hear you got it resolved. Don't forget to mark your question as answered!

Comment: Umm, I don't know how to do it. Should I write an answer and mark it as answered or are there something else that I should do?

Comment: Writing a quick description of what the problem was and you fixed it would work wonderfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been already pointed out, your problem was just the name of the field.

In your class the name was "Objects", but in your JSON response, it is "objects" (lowercase). The name of the variable in your program and in JSON must be exactly the same, because GSON allows you to get from the JSON response only those fields that you're interested in... so if it founds a JSON value in the response that doesn't correspond with any of your class attributes, GSON just ignore that value.

You could use the annotation `@SerializedName`, in this way:

```
@SerializedName("objects")
private Objects[] whateverName;
```

This way you can have different names in your class and in your JSON response.

NOTE: The type of the attribute doesn't have anything to do with your problem. Your class `Objects` should be written in uppercase to follow Java naming conventions...

Comment: Umm I didn't know SerializedName function and somehow it answered another question of mine, lol :) Thank you! I also selected this answer as accepted instead of mine ;)

Comment: No problem @Onur, I'm happy to help... and thanks for the accept! I'll upvote your answer too because you had realised the problem as well...

Answer (score 2):

The problem was miswritten of objects in EventResponse class

Making it look like this solved problem

```
public class EventResponse {
    public Meta meta;
    public objects[] objects; //I also changed the type for it not to have any
trouble.

    public EventResponse() {}

    public class Meta {
        public int limit;
        public String next;
        public int offset;
        public String previous;
        public int total_count;
    }

    public class objects {
        public String category;
        public String date;
        public String description;
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String resource_uri;
        public String venue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Class name should be capitalized and singular. perhaps `public Object[] objects;` is better. And the class declaration ofcourse be `public class Object { ...`. But then its the  OP who has chosen a poor name. I would suggest OP to go with `Thing`, not as good but better than `Object`